# The relation between integral of a function with the integral of its distribution function

Tags: measure-theory, fubini-tonelli-theorems

Let  $(X,A,\mu)$ be a measured space and $f$ a positive measurable function

Show that :

$$ \int_0^\infty \mu(\{f>t\})\,dt = \int_X f \, d\mu$$

I know it a common result, but I can't find the proof of it, has it a name?

Comment: This is a special case of theorem 8.16 from Rudin's "Real and complex analysis" book. You can find a proof there.

Comment: @guest the integrand on the right side is called the distribution function. I have edited the title of your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align}
\int_X f\,\mathrm d \mu &=\int_X\int_0^{f(x)}\,\mathrm d s\,\mu(\mathrm d x)\\
&=\int_X\int_0^\infty \boldsymbol 1_{\{f(x)>s\}}\,\mathrm d s\mu(\mathrm d x)\\
&\underset{Fubini}{=}\int_0^\infty\int_X\boldsymbol 1_{\{f(x)>s\}}\mu(\mathrm d x)\,\mathrm d s\\
&=\int_0^\infty \mu\{f(x)>s\}\,\mathrm d s.  
\end{align}

More generaly, you can prove that if $\varphi \in H^1(0,\infty )$ (and $f$ positive), then $$\int_X \varphi (f)\,\mathrm d \mu=\int_0^\infty \varphi '(s)\mu\{f(x)>s\}\,\mathrm d s,$$
holds.

Comment: Could you show in particular for instance that $ \int_{0}^{\infty} \mu({f>s})s^{p-1}ds = \int_{X}f^p d\mu$ ? Thanks for the answer btw

Comment: To apply Fubini you need to know $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite, this can be possible if $f$ is integrable as using Chebyshev's inequality $\mu\big(f^{-1}(\infty)\big)=0$. So what if $f$ is not integrable.

Comment: Another question how do you get second equality is not it $\int_0^{f(x)}ds=\int_0^\infty 1_{\{f(x)\geq s\}}ds$?

Comment: Note also, $\int_0^{f(s)}\ ds=\int_0^\infty1_{\{f(x)\geq s\}} ds=\int_0^\infty1_{\{f(x)> s\}} ds$ only holds for $f$ is integrable.

Comment: @Sumanta: I do not agree with your last comment. $$\int_a^b \mathrm d x:=\int_{\mathbb R}\boldsymbol 1_{(a,b)}\,\mathrm d x.$$More generally, on $(X,\mathcal M, \mu)$, if $E$ is measurable, then $$\int_E\,\mu(\mathrm d x):=\int_X\boldsymbol 1_E\,\mu(\mathrm d x).$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{aligned}\int_{0}^{\infty}\mu\left(f>t\right)dt & =\int_{0}^{\infty}\int1_{f>t}\left(x\right)\mu\left(dx\right)dt\\
 & =\int\int_{0}^{\infty}1_{f>t}\left(x\right)dt\mu\left(dx\right)\\
 & =\int\int_{0}^{f\left(x\right)}dt\mu\left(dx\right)\\
 & =\int f\left(x\right)\mu\left(dx\right)
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: I'm not so sure in what your answer is different from mine...

Comment: @Surb I am even convinced that there is no essential difference.

Comment: Could you show in particular that $ \int_{0}^{\infty} \mu({f>s})s^{p-1}ds = \int_{X}f^p d\mu$

Comment: Almost: $$\begin{aligned}\int_{0}^{\infty}\mu\left(f>s\right)s^{p-1}ds & =\int_{0}^{\infty}\int1_{f>s}\left(x\right)s^{p-1}\mu\left(dx\right)ds\\
 & =\int\int_{0}^{\infty}1_{f>s}\left(x\right)s^{p-1}ds\mu\left(dx\right)\\
 & =\int\int_{0}^{f\left(x\right)}s^{p-1}ds\mu\left(dx\right)\\
 & =\int\left[\frac{s^{p}}{p}\right]_{0}^{f\left(x\right)}\mu\left(dx\right)\\
 & =\frac{1}{p}\int f\left(x\right)^{p}\mu\left(dx\right)
\end{aligned}
$$Actually @Surb already mentioned this sort of generalization in his answer.

Comment: @Sumanta Doesn't Fubini always work if the integrand does not take negative values?

Comment: @Sumanta Let us do it with Tonelli (non-negative). But you are right about the condition of $\sigma$-finite measures. In this context I am reluctant though to elaborate on details like this. I don't think it played a part by posing the question.

Comment: @Sumanta For $s\geq0$ we have:$$1_{f>s}\left(x\right)=1\iff0\leq s<f\left(x\right)\iff1_{[0,f\left(x\right))}\left(s\right)=1$$

Comment: What is your argument for integrand $1_{\{f(x)\geq s\}}(\cdot)$? It cannot be $x$ nor $s$.